# calculate percentile using rolling window pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I create a pandas dataframe as

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1],[2],[3],[1],[2],[3],[1],[2],[3]])
df
Out[19]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  1
4  2
5  3
6  1
7  2
8  3
```

I calculate the 75% percentile on windows of length =3

```
df.rolling(window=3,center=False).quantile(0.75)
Out[20]: 
     0
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  2.0
3  2.0
4  2.0
5  2.0
6  2.0
7  2.0
8  2.0
```

then just to check I calculate the 75% on the first window separately

```
df.iloc[0:3].quantile(0.75)
Out[22]: 
0    2.5
Name: 0.75, dtype: float64
```

why I get a different value?

Comment: What version is your pandas? I think this is a bug, I get the right answer on 0.22.

Comment: I have the version 0.20.1

Comment: Update, and try again..

Comment: I ll break my code doing that...the new version of pandas is very different from the past one...

Comment: btw what do you get... 2.5 or 2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug, referenced in [GH9413](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9413) and [GH16211](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16211).

The reason, as given by the devs -

> It looks like the difference here is that `quantile` and `percentile` take
>   the weighted average of the nearest points, whereas rolling_quantile
>   simply uses one the nearest point (no averaging).

`Rolling.quantile` did not interpolate when computing the quantiles.

The bug has been fixed as of 0.21.

---

For older versions, the fix is using a `rolling_apply`.

```
df.rolling(window=3, center=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).quantile(0.75))

     0
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  2.5
3  2.5
4  2.5
5  2.5
6  2.5
7  2.5
8  2.5
```

Comment: @gabboshow I;'ve added a workaround as well, but beware, it is likely to be slow.